# MS Access database with a lot of manual data entry

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, data-entry

I'm building a database in Access that is going to be used to record substation loadings. There are 50 substations and each one has between 4 to 10 feeders, the data is the current that flows through these feeders and all of it will be typed in by hand.

How should I handle the user interface for this database? Should I create 50 forms or is there a better way to do this?

I should add that I also want to make this as dynamic as possible (where users can add new substations) hence my hesitance in making 50 separate forms.

Here's what I have in mind: A single form where you cycle through every substation from the substations table and the form is then populated with textboxes for feeders specific to that substation (using relationships).

Given my limited knowledge of the software, doing this requires a macro that'd create the textboxes and does the bounding, naming, positioning, etc. automatically which I haven't had any luck finding something like that online.

[Something like this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJrwq.png)

Comment: This sort of question is off topic for Stack Overflow, a site about debugging code. There are other sites in the Stack Exchange network like https://dba.stackexchange.com/ that are more suitable for database design questions. Even there this question may be too open to be on topic. An open discussion like this is better suited to a [forum](https://www.accessforums.net/forumdisplay.php?f=6) where you can have a long discussion. This is a Q&A site where one question has one answer.

Comment: User 785... is outlining your first step which is creating  normalized tables.  So look up database table normalization again and again until you get it.  You probably already have the data entry form in mind and making that form from the tables is the second step.  Once you have your tables and have used the relationship tool to hook them up then: click on each table and hit create form on the ribbon.  Play around with the forms Access makes and learn how they work.  Then start changing them until you get the form in your head.  Think Bansai tree or Elephant from marble block

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the extent of your question is. Also, I don't know how familiar you are with Access. Based on not having the answers to either of these questions there are 2 general things that need to be considered.

1. The database itself - storage of data
2. The user interface.

To get you rolling, I will address the database portion. I would typically create a table for the 50 substations first. Create that with a Primary Key which I would set to AutoIncrement. Create a second table that lists all the feeders for all 50 substations. From the information you have listed that means this table will have between 200 and 500 records. This table should also have a Primary Key (AutoIncrement it also) but it will also include a field for the Primary Key from the substations table which will then correctly associate the feeders to the appropriate substations. This feeder table will be what is called a child table because it is dependent on the substations table. A further complication is if the feeders are not dedicated to specific substations. In that case, you will need a third table, which is a many-to-many table. It will need its own Primary Key and will include the Primary keys from both the substations and feeders tables. That allows any one feeder to be associated to as many substations as is applicable.

I would have offered some guidance for the user interface but there is not enough information to do that.

I see you have added some information. I'm making the assumption that a feeder is dedicated to a single substation and a single substation may have more than 1 feeder. But no feeder serves more than 1 substation.

With that assumption the original database concept applies - parent table (substations) and child table (feeders).

It was nice that you provided the illustration because it defines what data needs to be input. But the method suggested to make the user interface requires too much work and will slow down the user interface. If you design the database as mentioned, where in the feeders table there is a field for the substations ID field. then create a main form that is bound to the substations table with a drop-down to select a substation. Add to this form what is called a subform - really just another form but it doesn't stand alone. Instead it is loaded on to the main form as any other control would be. Make it bound to the feeders table. Link the Parent/Child properties and when you select a substation from the drop-down the subform will automatically display records for each feeder that belongs to the substation.

Here's a Microsoft link on working with forms with subforms:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b

Also searching YouTube you will find a variety of tutorials on subforms. If the assumptiopn is correct, a feeder is dedicated to only 1 substation then do not look for tutorials that talk about subforms with many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've created the db itself and i'll make some changes based on your guidance. The main problem remains the interface.

Comment: I've added some additional user interface suggestions to the answer

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, your assumption is correct. Maybe it's time for me to finally start using sub-forms!
I've also started looking into the CreateControl method, but it seems like everybody in the world is advising against it.
This db is going to replace an Excel file that is currently being used to do the exact same thing, I intend to make this as easy to work with as the Excel file.

Comment: It will actually be a lot easier. The substation drop-down will automatically filter the subform to show a row for each feeder associated with the selected substation with whatever fields you have from the feeders table. No extra VBA code is needed if the main form is bound to the substation table and the drop-down is actually used to select a record from the substations table. In a Main/subform combination the Main form is limioted to displaying a single record which is exactly what you would need in the situation you have described.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create 50 forms.

In programming, it is very rarely a good idea to code 50 identical objects, rather than using one object 50 times.

Perhaps you see some problem with using the same form 50 times? If so, you should tell us what you think, so that we can help you by correcting your mistake.

Comment: Thanks, I've added more info to my question.