# MS Access #Name? error on textbox with dynamically set control source

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, data-entry

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68748665/ms-access-database-with-a-lot-of-manual-data-entry), while I kind of managed to accomplish what I had in mind (still debating whether or not I've chosen the best approach), I now have a problem regarding the dynamically set control sources for my textboxes.

When I use VBA code to set the control source I get **#Name?** errors unless I add the table to the form's Record Source. The trouble is, I'm working with a large amount of data and adding all of my tables to the record source will result in the "Too many fields defined" error.

I'm using the following code to set the control source:

```
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("feedersTBL", dbOpenDynaset)
    rst.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rst.EOF
            If Me!subID = rst!stationID Then
            i = i + 1
            Me.Controls("Feeder" & i).Visible = True
            
            Set rst2 = db.OpenRecordset("feedersLoadingTBL", dbOpenDynaset)
            
            'Binding the textboxes.
            For Each fld In rst2.Fields
                If fld.Name = rst!feederId Then
                    Me.Controls("Feeder" & i).ControlSource = rst!feederId
                    Debug.Print Me.Controls("Feeder" & i).ControlSource
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
         rst.MoveNext
     Loop
```

Note that the feedersLoadingTBL table has more than 400 columns which I've broken up into 4 tables.

I appreciate all and every help that I can get. Here's my access file if anyone wants to have a go at it (The names are in Persian).

[Google Drive link to the Access file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19A_F7Dp9Lei4xHxN0Yr39VvKVbQkEyxF/view?usp=sharing)

**Edit:**

I'm now using the DLookUp function as per @June7 recommendation. It works fine for a static field (like Date) but I can't seem to get the code to work for a dynamic field. Here's the new code:

```
[code and stuff]
   ⋮
   Me.Controls("Feeder" & i).ControlSource = "=DLookup(""[fld.Name]"", ""[feedersLoadingTBL]"", ""[time] =1"")"
   ⋮
[code and stuff]
```

""[fld.Name]"" is the part that will change in the loop. This is what feedersLoadingTBL table looks like:

[feedersLoadingTBL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpHi2.png)

Comment: Of course table must be in form RecordSource to bind textbox to field. Perhaps you should consider domain aggregate DLookup function.

Comment: The real problem here is the number of fields in your table - this will not be the only time that you have to work a lot harder to get things to work. The best thing is to go away and redesign the database schema, so that data is properly normalised.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for the comments. It appears that binding a textbox to a table that isn't in the record source IS possible. I tried it using the DLookUp function and it worked. I'm still in need of help, please check my edit.

Comment: That is not binding to field. It is setting unbound textbox with an expression. VBA is not necessary. Could put DLookup expression directly in each ControlSource property. `Date` is a reserved word and advise not to use reserved words as names.

Comment: Might want to post to a forum that allows attaching files. SO etiquette requires all data to analyze a question to be included in post. Links to SQLFiddle are acceptable to demonstrate queries. Images are discouraged. Few here will download file from file share site. Your Google drive link requires login anyway so your db is not even really available for review.

Comment: Sorry about the link, it should be fixed now. I know nobody wants to download a random database off the internet but I reckoned it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put dynamic reference within quote marks - concatenate. Can use apostrophe instead of doubled quotes.

`Me.Controls("Feeder" & i).ControlSource = "=DLookup('" & fld.Name & "', '[feedersLoadingTBL]', '[time] =1')"`

Comment: That code returns a 2465 error, I changed it a little:

From `'" & [fld.Name] & "'` to `'[" & fld.Name & "]'` Now the correct data is being shown in the textbox but it can not be edited because it's bound to the expression.

I have no idea what to do now.

Comment: Yes, I should have removed the brackets, edited answer. Brackets are needed as you modified if field names have spaces or special characters but certainly doesn't hurt to include. Unbound controls with an expression are never editable. If unbound control is set with a value instead, then every record will show the same value on a continuous or datasheet form. What are you really trying to accomplish? A form is supposed to be used for data entry/edit for a single table. Perhaps you should be using form/subform arrangement.

Comment: Thanks. I've given a bit of explanation in my prev. question (linked). Basically, I want the user to be able to go thru every substation (there's 50 of them) using the left and right arrow keys on the keyboard (already works) and enter the data by hand.

The data is then stored in table(s) for reports/graphs/etc.
I've promised my colleague that this is going to be as easy to work with as the Excel file he's currently using.

Can the record source of a subform be changed independently of the main form?
I feel like I need to rethink the way I've designed my database.

Comment: Yes, code can change subform RecordSource. When designing relational db, forget everything about Excel. I did look at your db. Appear to have a circular relationship with transTBL, feedersTBL, stationTBL.

Comment: Data entry in relational database often does not replicate paper forms or spreadsheets. If you really must go with the 'spreadsheet' entry with these 4 tables, the least coding approach is to build 4 forms to use as subforms. And maybe also use a Navigation Form for loading them.